# How to access Sets of pairs in c++

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define ll long long 

int main(){
    set<pair<ll,ll>>s;
    s.insert(make_pair(5,6));
    s.insert(make_pair(5,4));
    s.insert(make_pair(3,7));
    s.insert(make_pair(6,8));
    auto it=s.upper_bound(make_pair(4,0));
   
    cout<<*it.first<<endl;
}
```

It's printing:

> error: ‘struct std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >’ has no member named ‘first’

can someone answer me why it is happening and how to solve the error .

Comment: `.` has higher precedence than `*` so you need parens, `cout << (*it).first << endl;` or more simply `cout << it->first << endl;`

Comment: operator precedence, you want to know it

Comment: also, don't use [#include<bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Can i Know the reason @yaodav

Comment: read to links, but basically  #include<bits/stdc++.h> is an internal header for the compiler and it includes a lot of irrelevant data and using namespace std can cause function ambiguity. if in the std you have a function that has the same name as the one you define and the compiler don't know wich one to use or he is using the wrong one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this expression:

```
*it.first
```

the operator `.` has higher precedence than `*`. So the expression becomes:

```
*(it.first)
```

which is not correct.

You need to disambiguate with parentheses, like this:

```
(*it).first
```

or even better, use the `->` operator like this:

```
it->first
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get element of pair with :

```
 cout<<std::get<0>(*it)<<endl;
```